# Failed to acquire connection to Oracle

Tags: ssis

I am trying to migrate my data from SQL Server to Oracle through SSIS.A simple package has been created for this particular task which is working completely fine on my local machine. But when I am trying to deploy it on server using config file it is not able to acquire the Oracle connection and failing with below Error: 
[Execute SQL Task] Error: Failed to acquire connection "TargetDB". Connection may not be configured correctly or you may not have the right permissions on this connection.

Can anyone help please.

I have checked the permission of account and it is having read/write access.
Also tried validating the package using config file and it is successful. Only when the job runs I face this error.

Comment: 1) Is the Oracle driver installed and configured (TNSNAMES) on the target machine? 2) When you run it on the target machine, are you using the default (64 bit) server execution mode or (32 bit) development execution mode

Comment: Yes Oracle Driver is installed and configured. Also it is running on 64 bit. The issue has been resolved now. Config file has to include only required amount of properties such as server name, username,etc